# Convert repeated key value pairs text file to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, jq

I have a file that contains this format:

```
Cus Id: 1234
Cus Name: 10:/John Parks
Cus Type: temporary
Cus client: tesla;toyota
Dept Id: 111

Cus Id: 1235
Cus Name: 10:/William Parks
Cus Type: temporary
Cus client:
Dept Id: 222
```

How can I convert this to JSON format? Any methods bash, jq, or python is fine.

```
[
  {
    "Cus Id": 1234,
    "Cus Name": "10:/John Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": "tesla;toyota",
    "Dept Id": 111
  },
  { 
    "Cus Id": 1235,
    "Cus Name": "10:/William Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": "null",
    "Dept Id": 222
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're familiar with Python, that seems like a reasonably straightforward problem.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
jq -Rs '                        # 1. -Rs = read the input into a single string
    split("\n{2,}"; "")         # 2. split on sequences of blank lines
    | map(                      # 3. transform each paragraph into an object
        split("\n") 
        | map(scan("^([^:]+)(: (.*))?") | {key: first, value: last}) 
        | from_entries
    )
' data.file
```

outputs

```json
[
  {
    "Cus Id": "1234",
    "Cus Name": "10:/John Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": "tesla;toyota",
    "Dept Id": "111"
  },
  {
    "Cus Id": "1235",
    "Cus Name": "10:/William Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": null,
    "Dept Id": "222"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `reduce` the stream of raw-text (flag `-R`) `inputs` (flag `-n`) by iteratively building up the output array. Start with an array containing one empty object (`[{}]`), then `capture` each line's contents using regular expressions, and populate the currently last array item with it. If capturing fails structurally (testing the presence of a key), add another empty object.

```bash
jq -Rn 'reduce (inputs | capture("(?<k>[^:]+):\\s*(?<v>.*)|")) as $in (
  [{}]; if $in.k then last[$in.k] = $in.v else . + [{}] end
)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "Cus Id": "1234",
    "Cus Name": "10:/John Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": "tesla;toyota",
    "Dept Id": "111"
  },
  {
    "Cus Id": "1235",
    "Cus Name": "10:/William Parks",
    "Cus Type": "temporary",
    "Cus client": "",
    "Dept Id": "222"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AVM3l9IC4cA)

Going further:

- If you want to treat special values differently, adapt `$in.v` accordingly before the assignment. For example, to first test if values look like numbers and turn them into one, then test for empty strings and replace them with a special one (`"null"`), or else use the given string, you could go with something like `($in.v | tonumber? // (select(. == "") | "null") // .)`.
- If you want to treat special blocks differently, process the output after the reduction. For example, to prevent the generation of empty objects that occur if input blocks are separated by more then one empty line, you could go with something like `map(select(. != {}))`.

Comment: Does this drop the first line? Do we need `jq -Rn 'reduce ((., inputs) | ...` ?

Comment: @glennjackman `inputs` will only stream "all remaining" lines, i.e. it'll lack the first line if it is already bound to the context `.` which is the default behavior. One way to circumvent this "loss" is using `-n` to push a `null` as the new first input (making the real first line second, thus contained in the `inputs` stream), which is what I did. Another way would be to explicitly provide the already bound `.` alongside `inputs` as the generator stream for `reduce` (which is what you did with `(., inputs)`) but in this case there is no need to use `-n` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution:

```py
import json

def try_to_convert_to_int(val):
    try:
        val = int(val)
    except:
        pass
    return val

data, group = [], {}
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            if group:
                data.append(group)
            group = {}
        else:
            k, v = map(str.strip, line.split(':', maxsplit=1))
            group[k] = try_to_convert_to_int(v) if v else None

if group:
    data.append(group)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "Cus Id": 1234,
        "Cus Name": "10:/John Parks",
        "Cus Type": "temporary",
        "Cus client": "tesla;toyota",
        "Dept Id": 111
    },
    {
        "Cus Id": 1235,
        "Cus Name": "10:/William Parks",
        "Cus Type": "temporary",
        "Cus client": null,
        "Dept Id": 222
    }
]
```